How can I speed up symbolic integration of this highly oscillatory function?
I am trying to figure out how to speed up this symbolic integration. I have tried parallelization and numerical integration (both I am failing to implement).
Here is the function:
    1/1024((2 E^(I \[Pi] (-1 + Cos[delta] Cos[alpha - psi])) (2 Cos[delta]^2 + (-3 + Cos[2 delta]) Cos[2 (alpha - psi)]) (Sinc[\[Pi] (-1 + Cos[delta] Cos[alpha - psi])] + Sinc[\[Pi] + \[Pi] Cos[delta] Cos[alpha - psi]]) + 2 E^(I \[Pi] Cos[delta] Cos[alpha - psi - x]) (2 Cos[delta]^2 + (-3 + Cos[2 delta]) Cos[2 (alpha - psi - x)]) (Sinc[\[Pi] - \[Pi] Cos[delta] Cos[alpha - psi - x]] + Sinc[\[Pi] + \[Pi] Cos[delta] Cos[alpha - psi - x]]))^2)

Not ideal but if it speeds up the integration, I am willing to substitute x = Pi/2 and Psi = 0, however I found that this does not help at all.
The integral I want to apply to this expression is defined as:
   integralOperation[A_] := Module[{result},
   (*Perform the integration*)
   result = 
     Integrate[A*Cos[delta], {delta, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {alpha, 0, 2*Pi}]];
     (*Normalize by the factor 1/(4*pi)*)
     result = (1/(4*Pi))*result];

Does anybody know how to get this to run in an acceptable run time?
Thank you for your help!

The first thing that came to my mind: did you try recast the problem to an ODE and use the DSolve function?

I am not sure exactly what you mean. Would you mind elaborating a little more?

Oh I see what you mean, let me try that.
